# Pré-processamento OneHotEncoders ou LabelEncoder

Tags: python, sklearn

Estou fazendo o pré-processamento para um modelo de classificação mas me deparei com duas features (UF e Município).
Tendo em vista que são vários municípios e estados, estou na duvida se uso *LabelEncoder* ou *OneHotEncoder* para a codificação. Minha duvida se dá ao fato de que se eu usar o *LabelEncoder*, tenho medo de meu modelo achar que são categorias ordinais e atribuir peso diferentes para os estados e municípios.
Se eu usar o *OneHotEncoder*, terei muitas colunas pois são vários municípios e estados de todo o brasil. Mas se o fato de eu criar varias e varias colunas que terão o valor 0 em sua maioria, tenho medo de que isso atrapalhe o modelo.

Poderiam me orientar essa duvida?

Answer (score 1):

O correto é usar o `OneHotEncoder` - como você mesmo apontou, usar o `LabelEncoder` fará com que seu modelo "aprenda" que alguns estados/municípios são "maiores" ou "menores" do que outros.

O fato de produzir "muitas colunas" não é necessariamente um problema. Obviamente mais colunas = custo computacional um pouco maior, mas muitos modelos sabem lidar com colunas muitas codificadas via one-hot sem nenhuma dificuldade. O próprio `OneHotEncoder` do `scikit-learn` utiliza [matrizes esparsas](https://scipy-lectures.org/advanced/scipy_sparse/introduction.html#why-sparse-matrices) por padrão, o que gera um melhor uso de memória e processamento.